# How to remove noise from a set of data points assuming the data is normal but the noise is uniform?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, gaussian, noise, noise-reduction

I have a load of points inside some bounded rectangle of the plane. Most of them follow one of n bivariate normal distributions (the number n is unknown) but a *pretty small* amount of the remaining points instead follow one uniform distribution across the entire rectangle. I’m even willing to consider both the cases of when I have an estimate of how many of the points are noise, but prefer a solution which is agnostic of this.

In this image there are two gaussians and the red points are the uniform noise I want to filter out. Note that I’ve drawn this by hand so the good points might not look properly Gaussian. But in a real instance they will be!

[image]

I want to filter out that uniform noise so that I only have a mixture of gaussians left. With my assumption of normality, is there a fairly robust solution?

I have been thinking of using DBSCAN as a cleanup step to remove all of the noise but obviously have that problem of picking parameters.

I currently use GMMs to cluster my data and then some of the uniform noise ends up in its own clusters with massive, crazy covariance matrices that seem to go way outside of the rectangle. But I don’t know a robust way of choosing which clusters are the noisy ones and which are the true gaussians.

It seems I want a measure of density of the detected clusters. Or to relate the number of points with the area of the confidence region, as this ratio will be more exaggerated in the uniform cases.

Are there any papers on similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to solve this problem. Here is a simple approach that just uses k-means followed by a [normaltest](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.normaltest.html) for all the points in each cluster. The parameters that need to be set are the maximum number of clusters ever expected to be seen and a cutoff for maximum p-value for to the normal test. For each cluster, we do a normal test to see if the data points in the clusters roughly follow a normal distribution. Then, we only keep clusters (and data points) that are below the cutoff.

One risk of this approach is that some of the uniformly distributed noise points can really skew the distribution of the real clusters. Therefore, you may want to do some preprocessing to remove points that are too far away from a cluster center.

[image: Using k-means with normaltest]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from scipy.stats.mstats import normaltest


def gen_2d_normal(n):
    mean = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 2)
    cov = 1e-3*np.eye(2)
    return np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, n)

# used for generation
num_clusters = 3
num_points = 100
num_noise_points = 300

# hyperparameters to set
max_clusters = 8

# generate data
x, y = [], []
for cluster_idx in range(num_clusters):
    x.append(gen_2d_normal(num_points))
    y.extend([cluster_idx]*num_points)
x.append(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 2*num_noise_points).reshape(-1, 2))
y.extend([num_clusters]*num_noise_points)
x = np.vstack(x)
y = np.array(y)


clf = KMeans(max_clusters)
y_pred = clf.fit_predict(x)

for idx in range(max_clusters):
    plt.scatter(x[y_pred == idx][:, 0], x[y_pred == idx][:, 1], s=4)
    _, p_vals = normaltest(x[y_pred == idx])
    plt.text(clf.cluster_centers_[idx, 0]-0.04,
             clf.cluster_centers_[idx, 1]-0.07,
             '{:.2f}'.format(p_vals.mean()), fontsize=14)
plt.scatter(clf.cluster_centers_[:, 0], clf.cluster_centers_[:, 1],
            s=34, marker='X', color='k')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Gaussians are infinite, you should expect them to go out of the rectangle. On such data, I have seen EM work well with a 'noise' Gaussian that collects all the noise points, and where you would outlier ignore the model. You should be able to easily detect then because of their high variance and low density.

But the DBSCAN approach sounds very reasonable to try.